# jQuery assigning values to dropdown in a table

Tags: jquery, loops, html-table

I am trying to assign values to dropdown list in a table by looping each row. I got struck in some place where the tr looping is not correct. Some thing like `$("#myTable tr").each(function()` Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am trying to achieve this:

1. Split string with comma. loop through table rows
2. Assign left value before = to drop down value
3. Assign right value after = to textbox

[My Code Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/232HA/1/)

HTML:

```
<table width="100%" class="tblQueryBuilder">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Field</th>
        <th>Operator</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
        <td><div id="cItem" style="width: 14px; height: 14px; float: left;" class="unchkd"></div></td>
        <td>
            <select style="width: 150px;" class="selField">
                 <option value="Title" selected="selected">Title</option>
                 <option value="ProjectStatus" selected="selected">Project Status</option>
                 <option value="Tags">Tags</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select style="width: 150px;" class="selOperator">
                <option>=</option>
                <option>&lt;&gt;</option>
                <option>in</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width: 150px; height: 25px;" class="selValue"></td>
        <td>X </td>
        <td>= </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
        <td><div id="cItem" style="width: 14px; height: 14px; float: left;" class="unchkd"></div></td>
        <td>
            <select style="width: 150px;" class="selField">
                <option value="Title">Title</option>
                <option value="ProjectStatus">Project Status</option>
                <option value="Tags">Tags</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select style="width: 150px;" class="selOperator">
                <option>=</option>
                <option>&lt;&gt;</option>
                <option>in</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width: 150px; height: 25px;" class="selValue"></td>
        <td>X </td>
        <td>= </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
        <td><div id="cItem" style="width: 14px; height: 14px; float: left;" class="unchkd"></div></td>
        <td>
            <select style="width: 150px;" class="selField">
                <option value="Title">Title</option>
                <option value="Tags">Tags</option>
                <option value="ProjectStatus">Project Status</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select style="width: 150px;" class="selOperator">
                <option>=</option>
                <option>&lt;&gt;</option>
                <option>in</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width: 150px; height: 25px;" class="selValue"></td>
        <td>X </td>
        <td>= </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
var qry = 'Title=new project,Project Status=0,Tags=a';
        var qryRowCount = qry.split(',').length;

for (i = 0; i < qryRowCount; i++) {
    var fieldVal = qry.split(',')[i].split('=')[0];
    var displayVal = qry.split(',')[i].split('=')[0];

    $('.selField').val(fieldVal);
    $('.selValue').val(displayVal);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly ? because you code is very confusing, i cant understand what is the target

Comment: 1. Split variable with comma. loop through table rows
2. Assign left value before = to drop down value
3. Assign right value after = to textbox

Comment: Is this what you wanted ,http://jsfiddle.net/232HA/19/ ?

Comment: perfect. I appreciate your time. Thanks a ton. Could you please add this as answer?

Comment: thats good, i post the answer, you can check it as ANSWER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tagged each dropdown list and its corresponding textfield as `f1` to `f3` and `d1` to `d3`, so that these can be uniquely identified while looping through the table rows.

**JS CODE:**

```
  var qry = 'Title=new project,ProjectStatus=0,Tags=a';
  var qryStr = qry.split(',');
  var qryRowCount = qryStr.length;

for (i = 0; i < qryRowCount; i++) {
   var fieldVal = qryStr[i].split('=')[0];
   var displayVal = qryStr[i].split('=')[1];
   var fieldId = "#f" + (i + 1);
   var displayId = "#d" + (i + 1);
   $(fieldId).val(fieldVal);
   $(displayId).val(displayVal);
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/232HA/19/

I have tuned your code as well a bit, hope this solves your problem.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" onclick="setValues()" value="click"/>
<script>
function setValues(){
    $(".tblQueryBuilder tr").each(function(index, elem) {
        if (index == 0) return;

        var qry = $("input", this.cells[3]).val();
        var qryRowCount = qry.split(',').length;

        for (i = 0; i < qryRowCount; i++) {

            var fieldVal = qry.split(',')[i].split('=')[0];
            var displayVal = qry.split(',')[i].split('=')[0];

            $('.selField', this).append("<option value=" + fieldVal + ">" + displayVal + "</option>");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

by adding this to your code it will add to the select. is this what you needed?

Comment: i want qry as hard code value for now and split it
var qry = 'Title=new project,Project Status=0,Tags=a';

Comment: so move it out of the function

Comment: I tried it http://jsfiddle.net/232HA/21/ but unable to show splitted values as selected values. I see values added to dropdowns.